# Centering text over an image

Tags: html, css

I know this question has been asked a lot, and I have certainly benefited much from previous solutions. However, I just can't seem to get this to work. On my web page, the following code results in the text being centered over the entire page, not just the parent `div`. For some reason, the code snippet shows the text over the first 'row' of images, but then no others. What am I doing wrong?

```css
body, html {
 height: 100vh;
}

.hover_img {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}

.hover_img img {
 display: inline-block;
 max-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
 -webkit-columns: 20em 3;
    -moz-columns: 20em 3;
    columns: 20em 3;
 
 -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    column-gap: 1em;
 
 margin-top: 2em;
}

.hover_img h4 {
 color: black;
}

.hover_img:hover img {
 opacity: .2;
}

.hover_img:hover .center_text {
 display: block;
}

.center_text {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 display: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Images</title>
 </head>
 
  <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="hover_img">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
    <div class="center_text">
          <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
        </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="hover_img">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
    <div class="center_text">
          <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
        </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="hover_img">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
    <div class="center_text">
          <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
        </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="hover_img">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
    <div class="center_text">
          <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
        </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="hover_img">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
    <div class="center_text">
          <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
        </div>
   </div>
      
   <div class="hover_img">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
    <div class="center_text">
          <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
        </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="hover_img">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
    <div class="center_text">
          <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
        </div>
   </div>
      
   <div class="hover_img">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
    <div class="center_text">
          <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
        </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="hover_img">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
    <div class="center_text">
          <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
        </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: put position: relative for .hover_img class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `position: relative;` to the `.hover_img` class. Your text is using absolute positioning and will be positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor element. If no ancestor has positioning, then it will be relative to the browser viewport.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100vh;
}

.hover_img {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}

.hover_img img {
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
  -webkit-columns: 20em 3;
  -moz-columns: 20em 3;
  columns: 20em 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
  -moz-column-gap: 1em;
  column-gap: 1em;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.hover_img h4 {
  color: black;
}

.hover_img:hover img {
  opacity: .2;
}

.hover_img:hover .center_text {
  display: block;
}

.center_text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  display: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Images</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="hover_img">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      <div class="center_text">
        <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hover_img">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      <div class="center_text">
        <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hover_img">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      <div class="center_text">
        <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hover_img">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      <div class="center_text">
        <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hover_img">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      <div class="center_text">
        <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hover_img">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      <div class="center_text">
        <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hover_img">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      <div class="center_text">
        <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hover_img">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      <div class="center_text">
        <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hover_img">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
      <div class="center_text">
        <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a parent container with positioning context:

```
.hover_img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    position: relative; // <-- give positioning context!
}
```

By adding `position: relative;` to a parent container the text will position itself relative to this element.

This article provides a good explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

```css
body, html {
 height: 100vh;
}

.hover_img {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  position: relative;
}

.hover_img img {
 display: inline-block;
 max-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
}

.container {
 -webkit-columns: 20em 3;
    -moz-columns: 20em 3;
    columns: 20em 3;
 
 -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    column-gap: 1em;
 
 margin-top: 2em;
}

.hover_img h4 {
 color: black;
}

.hover_img:hover img {
 opacity: .2;
}

.hover_img:hover .center_text {
 display: block;
}

.center_text {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 display: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Images</title>
 </head>
 
  <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="hover_img">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
    <div class="center_text">
          <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
        </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="hover_img">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
    <div class="center_text">
          <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
        </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="hover_img">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
    <div class="center_text">
          <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
        </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="hover_img">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
    <div class="center_text">
          <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
        </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="hover_img">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
    <div class="center_text">
          <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
        </div>
   </div>
      
   <div class="hover_img">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
    <div class="center_text">
          <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
        </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="hover_img">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
    <div class="center_text">
          <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
        </div>
   </div>
      
   <div class="hover_img">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
    <div class="center_text">
          <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
        </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="hover_img">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
    <div class="center_text">
          <h4>Here is some information about the image...</h4>
        </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```